# Hot to manipulate submitted data in Symfony 2 Forms Framework?

Tags: forms, mongodb, symfony

I have some MongoDB document related to some categories. Categories are stored in MongoDB document in tree structure with sequential ID for every category. In my entity document i have a field where i wanna store array of categories IDs in flat array instead of tree.
In Symfony 1.4 with Doctrine ORM it was possible to manipulate  submitted data in validator objects for a field or post validator for an entire form. I could totally transform submitted data into a different array and pass it to a object. 
How can I manipulate data in Symfony 2 Forms Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the DataTransformers are what you need. You can find a cookbook entry in the official symfony documentation that explains how to use it : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html